# How to create operators from list in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I need to copy tables from MySQL to BigQuery daily.
My workflow is:

1. `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator`
2. `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`

This works for a single process (say `Categories`).

Example:

```
BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES = Variable.get("tables_categories")
...

import_categories_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_categories',
    mysql_conn_id='c_mysql',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_a',
    approx_max_file_size_bytes = 100000000, #100MB per file
    sql = 'import_categories.sql',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name_categories,
    dag=dag)

gcs_to_bigquery_categories_op = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id='load_categories_to_BigQuery',
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template_categories,
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    source_objects=[uri_template_categories_read_from],
    schema_fields=Categories(),
    src_fmt_configs={'ignoreUnknownValues': True},
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
    bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID)


import_categories_op >> gcs_to_bigquery_categories_op
```

Now, Say I want to scale it up and have it work with 20 more tables.. Is there a way to do it without writing the same code 20 times?
I'm looking for a way to do something like:

```
BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES = Variable.get("tables_categories")
BQ_TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS = Variable.get("tables_products")
....
BQ_TABLE_NAME_ORDERS = Variable.get("tables_orders")
list = [BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES,BQ_TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS,BQ_TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS  ]
for item in list:
    GENERATE THE OPERATORS PER TABLE
```

so that will create `import_categories_op` , `import_products_op` , `import_orders_op` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact it's exactly what you described. Simply instantiate your operators in your for loop. Make sure your task ids are unique and you're set:

```
BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES = Variable.get("tables_categories")
BQ_TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS = Variable.get("tables_products")

list = [BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES, BQ_TABLE_NAME_PRODUCTS]

for table in list:
    import_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id=`import_${table}`,
        mysql_conn_id='c_mysql',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_a',
        approx_max_file_size_bytes = 100000000, #100MB per file
        sql = `import_${table}.sql`,
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        filename=file_name,
        dag=dag)
    gcs_to_bigquery_op = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id=`load_${table}_to_BigQuery`,
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
        source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
        source_objects=[uri_template_read_from],
        schema_fields=Categories(),
        src_fmt_configs={'ignoreUnknownValues': True},
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        skip_leading_rows = 1,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
        bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID)


    import_op >> gcs_to_bigquery_op
```

You can simplify this if you store all tables in a single variable:

```
// bq_tables = "table_products,table_orders"
BQ_TABLES = Variable.get("bq_tables").split(',')

for table in BQ_TABLES:
    ...
```

## Edit: Task references vs IDs

Luis asked about how only the task IDs need to change (and not the references to the tasks). Actually, you don't even need to refer to your tasks for anything but adding some details to them after creation (like upstream and downstream dependencies), because they're stored in the DAG object on creation, and that's all the DAG parser is looking for. Once the DAG parser finds a DAG object in the global scope, it uses it. It doesn't know what names the tasks were referred to as in the global scope, it only knows that those tasks are listed on the DAG object, and that they list each other upstream or downstream.

I would have made this a comment on this answer, but I wanted to show the following code to explain what I mean a bit more obviously (in which I use `with DAG` to avoid assigning each task to the dag, and the bitwise-shift operator upstream/downstream assignment to avoid needing to even refer to the tasks by a reference, and python3's formatted f-strings):

```
// bq_tables = "table_products,table_orders"
BQ_TABLES = Variable.get("bq_tables").split(',')

with DAG('…dag_id…', …) as dag:
    for table in BQ_TABLES:
        MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
            task_id=f'import_{table}',
            sql=f'import_{table}.sql',
            …  # all params except notably there's no `dag=dag` in here.
        ) >> GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(  # Yup, …
            task_id=f'load_{table}_to_BigQuery',
            …  # again all but `dag=dag` in here.
        )
```

Sure, it could have been `t1=…; t2=…; t1>>t2; …` but why name references?

Comment: So you are saying that the operators names can be generic and I need to change only the task_ids ?

Comment: Yes, you don't have to keep holding variable references to Tasks (Operator instances). If you give them unique ids and properly assign them to your DAG, all is set.